# How to set spinner selection from an arrayadapter with an arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, android-spinner, pojo

Well I have an arraylist from my sqlite data. And I'm setting this arraylist on my arrayadapter of my spinner.

Here's how I do it:

```
 public ArrayList<AttendantModelNames> getAllAttendantNames() {
        ArrayList<AttendantModelNames> attendantModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        hp = new HashMap();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ATTENDANTS, null);
        res.moveToFirst();
        while (!res.isAfterLast()) {
            AttendantModelNames l_att = new AttendantModelNames();
            l_att.setname(res.getString(res
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)));
            attendantModelArrayList.add(l_att);
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, attendantModelArrayList.toString());
        res.close();
        return attendantModelArrayList;
    }
```

Then my AttendantModelNames POJO:

```
public class AttendantModelNames {
    String name;

    public String getname() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setname(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Then on my spinner:

```
private void setSpinner() {
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(com.duka.R.id.spinner_toolbar);
        ArrayList<AttendantModelNames> modelArrayList = ah.getAllAttendantNames();
        ArrayAdapter<AttendantModelNames> dataAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<AttendantModelNames>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, modelArrayList);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

int selectionPosition= dataAdapter.getPosition(modelArrayList.get(position).getname());
spinner.setSelection(selectionPosition);
```

I tried setting this but doesn't seem to work, says:

> get(int) in arraylist cannot be applied to (java.lang.String) on
>   position

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: What's this `attname`?  And also set adaptor and then call `setSelection()`

Comment: `attname` is the string i would like to set as the pre-selected name. Also can't you see i already set the adapter before `setSelection()`?

Comment: Sorry my bad.. I was looking at the commented code..

Comment: Any ideas on this?

Comment: I suggest you keep an index in the POJO class and call `.getIndex()` rather than `getName()`

Comment: And how are you getting the `position` in `get(position)`?

Comment: @Sanoop I managed to resolve it by going back to the root of my problem. Thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i resolved my issue:

I started out by returning an list of type string:

```
public List<String> getAllAttendantNames() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ATTENDANTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);//selectQuery,selectedArguments

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                list.add(cursor.getString(2));//adding 2nd column data
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // closing connection
        cursor.close();

        // returning lables
        return list;
    }
```

Then set up spinner:

```
private void loadSpinnerData() {
        List<String> labels = ah.getAllAttendantNames();

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, labels);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        int spinnerPosition = dataAdapter.getPosition(s_attname);
        Log.d("spinner_set_selection", s_attname + spinnerPosition);
        spinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
    }
```

And ofcourse `onCreate()`:

```
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
             // Loading spinner data from database
        loadSpinnerData();
```